# TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'. Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular7

### What I'm Using

- Angular
- Angular Material

### What I'm Trying to Achieve

I am using the DatePicker Module from Angular Material and after a user clicks on a date I am trying to use insertBefore to add an element before the next table row

**Example:**

Start With:

```
<table>
    <tbody> //parent
        <tr role="row">Stuff</tr> //target
        <tr role="row">Stuff</tr> //next row
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Start With:

```
<table>
    <tbody> //parent
        <tr role="row">Stuff</tr>
        <tr role="row'>NEW ROW</tr> // NEW ROW
        <tr role="row">Stuff</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Where I'm Stuck

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is
>   not of type 'Node'. Angular Material

You can find an example of the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvi8e9

Here is the code for what I getting the error with:

Template

```
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
  <mat-calendar #calendar [(selected)]="selectedDate" (monthSelected)="monthSelected($event)" (selectedChange)="onDateChanged($event);"></mat-calendar>
</div>
```

Component

```
  onDateChanged(date) {
    let targetDate = event.currentTarget;
    let currentWeek = this.renderer.parentNode(targetDate);
    let nextWeekRow = this.renderer.nextSibling(currentWeek);
    let parentNode = this.renderer.parentNode(currentWeek);

    let p = this.renderer.createElement('p');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('Test');

    this.renderer.appendChild(p, text);
    this.renderer.insertBefore(parentNode, nextWeekRow, p);
  }
```

Comment: Please post the code itself here directly.

Comment: I added the code that's causing the error, but im not sure how it will help without the context of the rest of the code. I'm using the DatePicker module from Angular Material

Comment: ```p``` isn't a node, it's a string.

Comment: The error isn't even referring to the paragraph tag. It's saying "nextWeekRow" is not a node. "parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'"

I changed it, to show thats not the cause of the issue

Comment: `mat-calendar` did you mean `mat-datepicker`?, also mat-datepicker has a `stateChanges` event you can subscribe to instead of creating your own function, Also I don't think the function is passing an html native element